How to use differential growth?
I'm relatively new at Blender and I'm trying to get my dfferential line growth to grow across a mesh preferably the ground or a staircase.
I'm struggling to get the simulation I've made to grow across the mesh. I followed this video excatly.




"I'm struggling to get the simulation I've made to grow across the mesh" is way too little information to help you. Also, I don't think anyone will spend 15 min to watch a tutorial + reproduce your 50+ nodes without any guidance or information from your part.
